# Getting Error When Attaching Video URL To Product

Tags: magento2.3, integration, product-video, youtube

Done With API Key Configurations:

Error Getting when entering url

[image]

Comment: Have you configured Youtube API in magento configurations

Comment: @RajMohanR yes I configure.i follow that tutorial .. the link is: http://magenticians.com/add-video-to-product-in-magento-2/

Comment: So if you have created the API new it might take 1 or 2 hrs to reflect

Comment: Bro, I configured that process 4 hours ago I was also thinking that it might take some time to reflect according to the popup alert, But its already 5 hours now. But still getting that alert.

Comment: Have you checked the API key? Please try creating the API key again

Comment: yes, bro, I get a new one and getting the same alert

Comment: It is displaying a project id right is the one which you have created in Google API